# Compiling Issue. C#

Tags: c#

Got an issue.

When I recompile my code, non of the changes take effect. I've tried to add MessageBoxes, change labels, the color of text .. everything. When I recompile nothing changes, it seems to load old code.

Any idea what's going on? Is there a cache or anything?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue when I had a GAC'd version of the same DLL that I tried to debug. During load, the runtime would pick up the version from the GAC rather than the one I just compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are running the same code you changed? Try single steppings through the app rather than run.

Answer (score 1):

Open up your application directory, delete the debug folder.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clean your build output. Right-click on the Solution (or Project) icon in the solution browser and select 'clean'.

Comment: Hmmm, I can't seem to find a clean option. I'm using Visual C# 2008 Express.

Comment: Remove the compiled files manually - they are probably in a folder inside your project called .\bin\Debug

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the "Modules" window (from the Debug->Windows menu).  This will show you where the runtime is loading your assemblies from.

Answer (score 0):

Build -> Rebuild Solution. This will do clean up and build for your.

Answer (score 0):

And very rarely, delete the .suo file associated with the project.. Which will force rebuilding..

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new project.